# Need mutator methods how do I do them

Tags: java

I am doing a UML and I am not quite sure how to do these mutator methods I am supposed to do this:

```
+turnOn(): void       //sets on to true
+turnOff(): void      //sets on to false
+channelUp(): void    //increases channel by 1 if on, rolls to 1 after maximum
+channelDown(): void  //decreases channel by 1 if on, rolls to maximum after 1
+volumeUp(): void     //increases the volume by 1 if on and less than maximum
+volumeDown(): void   //decreases volume by 1 if on and greater than 0
+toString( ): String  //returns the current state(instance variable values)
```

my code right now: (keep in mind the mutator part isn't right)

```
public class TV {
    private int volume;
    private int channel;
    private boolean on;
    private int maxVolume;
    private int maxChannel;

    TV() {
        volume = 1;
        channel = 1;
        on = false;
        maxVolume = 1;
        maxChannel = 1;
    }
    public int getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public boolean isOn() {
        return on;
    }

    public int getMaxChannel() {
        return maxChannel;
    }

    public int getMaxVolume() {
        return maxVolume;
    }
    public void setChannel(int i) {
        if (isOn() && i >= 1 && i <= maxChannel) channel = i;
    }

    public void setVolume(int i) {

        if (isOn() && i >= 0 && i <= maxVolume) volume = i;
    }

    public void setMaxChannel(int i) {
        maxChannel = i;
    }

    public void setMaxVolume(int i) {
        maxVolume = i;
    }

    // + turnOn() * * This is where the mutator methods begin I need help here * *

    // if (channel == maxChannel) channel = 1;
    // else channel++;

    //if (channel == 1) channel = max;
    //else channel--;

    // if (volume == maxVolume) volume = 1;
    // else channel++;
    //if (volume == 1) volume = max;
    // else channel--;

    public string toString() {
        return "channel: " + channel + "\nvolume: " + volume +
            "\non: " + on + "\nmax Channel: " + maxChannel +
            "\nmax Volume: " + maxVolume;
    }
}
```

Comment: Trigonometreh, If one of the answers bellow were correct please don't forget to accept it so that the stackoverflow community can benefit from our knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample methods:

```
public void turnOn() {
   this.on = true;
}

public void channelUp() {
   if (on) {
      if (channel == maxChannel) {
         channel = 1;
      }
      else {
         channel++;
      }
   }
}

public void volumeDown() {
   if (on && volume > 0) {
      volume--;
   }
}
```

Other methods follows the same logic.

Strings in java are objects, so your toString method signature should read `public String toString()`.

Comment: Done (and included the `on` rule too), but please try to do your homework, otherwise you will not learn.

Answer (score 2):

Mutator generally means the same things as 'setter'

So in your above code, a 'getter' would be:

```
public int getMaxChannel() {
  return maxChannel;
}
```

and a 'mutator' or 'setter' would be:

```
public void setMaxChannel(int maxChannel) {
  this.maxChannel = maxChannel;
}
```

Comment: oh okay, and I have to reference these from the UML TestTV.java I have, heres a screenshot on what I need to add I'm clueless on how to do so: http://gyazo.com/817dc6972e03251d7f437d754ef6c6b2

Answer (score 0):

We use setters and mutator as interchangeably.

> A mutator method is used to set a value of a private field. It follows
>   a naming scheme prefixing the word "set" to the start of the method
>   name. These methods do not have a return type and accept a parameter
>   that is the same data type as their corresponding private field. The
>   parameter is then used to set the value of that private field.

Below are some examples of mutators or setters:

```
public void setMaxChannel(int i) {
        maxChannel = i;
    }

public void setChannel(int c) {
        channel=c;
    }
```